# Creating A Dynamic Credit Card Dropdown with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, for-loop

I am trying to create a dynamic dropdown that will take the current year and iterate another 15 years to it so I don't have to continue to update the credit card year dropdown field. I have successfully built the for loop but cannot seem to figure out how to put this inside a select tag.

Any help would be great!

Here is the for loop that iterates the date. Here is my [CodePen](http://www.codepen.io/jbatzel1Development/pen/kebpn)

```
var date = new Date().getFullYear();
var length = date + 16;

for(var i = date; i < length; i++){
  document.write("<br/>" + i + "<br/>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, definitely you want to end up with something similar to the following, right?

```
<select>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <!-- ... -->
    <option value="2027">2027</option>
</select>
```

So you should be creating `<option>` elements in your loop, and throwing them into a `<select>` element. Something a little like this:

```
var year = new Date().getFullYear(),
    $select = $('select').empty()  // be sure to select the proper, ahem, select
    ;

for(var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    $('<option>')          // creates an <option> element
        .val(year + i)     // sets its value
        .text(year + i)    // sets the text inside
        .appendTo($select) // puts it into your <select>
    ;
}
```

Several points for optimization in my script (favor adding all elements in one go instead of one by one; consider creating a template and just cloning, instead of making jQuery parse your HTML string; etc), but I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Thanks Neil, that was very helpful and interesting to see how you did it vs some of the people above.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date().getFullYear();
var length = date + 16;

var select = $("#select");
select.empty();
for(var i = date; i < length; i++){
  select.append($('<option></option>').val(i).html(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

without using jquery it looks like this

```
 var options = "";
 for(var i = date; i < length; i++){
     options += "<option value='"+ i +"'>" + i + "<option/>";
 }
 document.getElementById('select').innerHTML = options;
```

Comment: You should be creating `<option>` elements appended into the `<select>`, not raw `<br/>`s.

Comment: just noticed the mistake tks :P

Answer (score 0):

Using just plain JavaScript:

```
var date = new Date().getFullYear(),
    sel = document.getElementById('select'),
    prop = 'textContent' in document.createElement() ? 'textContent' : 'innerText',
    opt;

for (var i = 0, len = 16; i < len; i++) {
    opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = date + i;
    opt[prop] = date + i;
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5xfjQ/1/).

Comment: Thanks! It was nice to see how to do this using pure JavaScript!

Comment: You're very welcome, I'm glad to have helped. Do review the answers and see which, if any, best answer your question and, if your question is answered appropriately, consider marking that best answer as 'accepted.' That rewards the person who (most) helped you with 15 points. =)

Answer (score 0):

here you have and I would also recommend you to use a javascript framework, JQuery for instance.

```
var date = new Date().getFullYear();

var length = date + 16;

document.getElementById('select').innerHTML = '';

for(var i = date; i < length; i++){

  document.getElementById('select').innerHTML += '<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Richard Neil Ilagan said, you should be creating `<option>` elements and appending them to your `<select>` element. Here's a solution without jQuery

```
var select = document.getElementById("select");
var startYear = new Date().getFullYear();
var option, currentYear;

for(var i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
  currentYear = startYear + i;

  option = document.createElement("option");
  option.setAttribute("value", currentYear);
  option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(currentYear));

  select.appendChild(option);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vincent, It looks like there are a whole bunch of ways to do this!